# Grails Jasper plugin, how to disable white background when export to excel?

Tags: grails, jasper-reports

I am using the Jasper plugin and would like to disable the white background when exporting to excel. How can i do that?

/Marco

Comment: What do you mean `to disable the white background`?

Comment: When i export the report as XLS format, the cells have a white background and all cell lines are white.

Comment: Do you want to set background color for all cell and color for cell's lines? Did you try to do the same in iReport?

Comment: No i want the white background to be gone.. i want no background color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the custom property `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background` to false in the report jrxml. For example:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background" value="false" />
```